# Rename [minecraft-education-edition] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-rename-request

In the latest update, "Minecraft: Education Edition" was renamed only as "Minecraft Education" with a restyled app, as confirmed by the changelog and the new site icon:

[image]

So, should we rename the [minecraft-education-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-education-edition) tag, too?

Answer (score 2):

I'm kinda split.

Because on one part yeah, it's now "Minecraft Education" and not "Minecraft: Education Edition", but down to the metal, it is still the educative edition of Minecraft, and we have lots of other tags that are not the big name on top of the game.

Things like:

- minecraft-java-edition
- minecraft-bedrock-edition

So since we are talking about an edition, separate like the java or bedrock ones, that would go the way of keeping [minecraft-education-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-education-edition) as is.

I'm leaning more in the direction of leaving it be as of now.

Comment: Can't disagree with that, but we should have [minecraft-education] as a synonym at least.

Comment: That is true. I'll add it.

Comment: I added the synonym [tag:minecraft-education].  I was also "meh" on changing the name too.

Comment: _" its not education and not education edition"_ What do you mean by this? Did you mean "its **now** education and not education edition"?

Comment: yep, mistype. I blame it was early this morning

Comment: @TimmyJim no worries, I wasn't proposing a tag rename, just asking for opinions about that

Comment: @pinckerman you could always self answer your reasoning on why it should be renamed, and see how the community votes.

Comment: @TimmyJim I don't have a real reason beside the actual "rebranding", both Java and Bedrock still use -edition, so I'm ok